# What software or series of softwares would you recommend for online booking form

Tags: forms, booking

We are a simple website that offer cleaning services for domestic customers and we sub-contract local cleaners to perform our jobs. Currently our booking form only offer service requests when upon such, we have to call the customer and schedule an appointment over the phone at a mutually convenient time and date.
We are looking for a service booking software, or a series of software which must offer the following features:

1. Highly customisable fields with conditional logic
2. When an user fills out a certain information into the booking form, he must be prompted with a list of cleaners who:

   1. Matches the user's skills requirements (f.x. Can Iron clothes)
   2. Matches the user's property area (f.x. Can service north Berlin)
   3. Is available at the user's requested time and date (f.x. Is available at 3 PM on Monday for 3 hours)
3. When the user's picks out his cleaner, to be prompted to a payment gateway. When making a payment, an appointment to be scheduled.

I'm mentioning a series of software as even Zappier integrations are fine for us, as far as all this thing works. We are currently using JotForm for collecting customer's requirements, information and details. Bad thing is that not most of the users are even answering our calls/emails after form submission. We believe such booking form would allows us to generate more leads and actual bookings.

Thank you!